# Get username logging on from task scheduler

Tags: task-scheduler

I'm using Windows Server 2008 task scheduler to run a task when a user logs on, but I would like some way of the task being able to access the name of the user who is logging on.  I don't know if there is an environment variable I can access in the task or I can add something in as a parameter when the task runs?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

You might want to [attach the trigger of your task to a certain event so you can reference the event's data](http://blogs.technet.com/b/otto/archive/2007/11/09/find-the-event-that-triggered-your-task.aspx). I can't exactly tell you what event you would want to attach the trigger to (e.g. is it only remote logins you're interested in, etc.), but I think this might very well be what you're looking for.

Hope it helps!

**Original answer:**

You might want to have a look at [this handy list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows), which should give you an idea. In the most simple of cases `%USERNAME%` might just be what you need  (e.g. in a batch file you might run).

Comment: %USERNAME% returns the username which the task is running under, which is always the same user - I want to know the username that has logged on

Comment: Gotcha. Changed my answer to what I hope is somewhat more appropriate :).